# Apache httpd permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, httpd

I have created a directory

```
/xyz/www
```

With the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 myuser developers
```

I edited my http.conf:

```
DocumentRoot "/xyz/www/"
<Directory "/xyz/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I get 403 error: `You don't have permission to access / on this server.`

Looking in the logs:

```
(13)Permission denied: Can't open directory for index: /xyz/www/
```

I've tried recursively adding 777 permissions but still have the same issue.

Comment: Is SELinux enabled?

Comment: Yes it is enabled...when I setenforce 0...this fixes the problem!!

Comment: @zero_r can you suggest how to fix this? not familiar with SELinux

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permission denied in vhost document root](http://serverfault.com/questions/409464/permission-denied-in-vhost-document-root)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you have to do is copy the same *security context* /var/www/html has. To do this:

```
# ls -la --context /var/www/html
drwxr-xr-x root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t .
drwxr-xr-x root root system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t ..
-rw-r--r-- root root user_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t index.html
```

Then you have to set it to your desire DocumentRoot as follows:

```
# chcon -R system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t /xyz/www
```

Comment: I'm not sure how long I would have beaten my head against that problem... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Is your target directory NTFS or ext3 ?
Please check SELinux context of target directory using

```
ls -a --context /target/directory
```

If the context of target directory is alike

```
system_u:object_r:fusefs_t:s0
```

using

```
setsebool -P httpd_use_fusefs on
```

might work for you as it could be just a boolean issue for the filesystem.  Please do confirm the security aspects of Booleans as I'm unaware of them.

[SELinux Booleans](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/SelinuxBooleans)

Answer (score 2):

Directories normally require the `x` permission for processes to access files within them.  With the permissions you currently have, you would be able to `ls` the directory but not `cd` into it.  Since the directory is owned by you, Apache will be running with the permissions of the third column.

Try `chmod +x /xyz/www`.

If you still have problems, check the permissions on `/xyz/` as well.

Comment: even with 777 permissions on all files/directories I still get the same error.

Comment: The next place I generally look after that is SELinux or Apparmor but it looks like someone already suggested that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - the `chcon` command fixed it.

I was creating an install server and wanted my images under `/export/install/<image>` with a symlink in the doc root. I was certain my `httpd.conf` settings were correct.

The directories & files were **755** & **644** respectively, and the **apache** user could traverse the tree so what was it?

I used a similar command to the one above but used the **reference** option:

```
% chcon -R --reference=/var/www/html /export
```

Could have just shut off `selinux` but I want to learn how to live with it.

Answer (score 1):

You should also add `<Directory /xyz/www>` section to apache config with something like

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: Did that already...amended post to add more clarity

Comment: And reloaded httpd ?

Comment: This is a good point. The default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server does not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www. Check `apache2.conf` for this statement: `<Directory />
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride None
 Require all denied
</Directory>`

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux

> The 'chcon' command may be used to change SELinux security context of
>   a file or files/directories in a similar way to how 'chown' or 'chmod'
>   may be used to change the ownership or standard file permissions of a
>   file.

chcon -Rv --type=httpd_sys_content_t /xyz/www